# Generating JAR and POM file following the Maven repository layout?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a project where I need to generate the jar and pom files following the same method with the maven plugin **maven-install-plugin** generates in the local repository, as can be seen in the return of the IDE to build the project:

```
--- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ projeto-java ---
Installing C:\Users\matheus\Java\Projeto-Java\target\Projeto-java-1.2.3.jar to C:\Users\matheus\.m2\repository\br\com\xxx\java\projeto-java\1.2.3\projeto-java-1.2.3.jar
Installing C:\Users\matheus\Java\Projeto-Java\pom.xml to C:\Users\matheus\.m2\repository\br\com\xxx\java\projeto-java\1.2.3\projeto-java-1.2.3.pom
```

I need the files **project-java-1.2.3.pom** and **project-java-1.2.3.jar** are placed in specific directory, how can I change the directory where the plugin places or have another plugin to do that?

Comment: Why do you need that? What is the purpose of this? Default in Maven is the `target` folder...

Comment: The purpose would be to share the POM and the JAR in a shared directory with others.

Comment: You know that Maven already has a solution for this. Just use mvn install and other project on your machine can consume it as a dependency. Or use a repository manager where you deploy it and other in your company can consume it...That's the Maven Way..

Comment: @khmarbaise I found this very interesting solution proposed by RITZ XAVI you think working in this way is wrong?

Comment: This solution is a kind of miusing and ingnoring the concepts of Maven (local repository is not intended for sharing artifacts for different users only for a single user). A repository is intended for sharing artifacts.

Comment: I understand and thank you for clarification ... and with respect to Maven Way you recommend me some material that I understand better the functioning of this tool?

Comment: @MatheusOliveira, always remember that maven's way is `convention over configuration`. We should not play around with what maven does things by default(unless absolutely necessary). If you want to share your artifacts amongst others, the right way would be to use a repository manager such as [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/#os-arti).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the location of your local maven repository (which is `.m2` by default) by editing settings.xml file in your maven installation folder.

You can find your settings.xml file in `{M2_HOME}\conf\setting.xml`.
To change the default local maven repository location, add the below code within the `<settings>` tag :

`<localRepository>D:/location-where-you-want</localRepository>`

Note that, this will now start sending all the artifacts (jars, wars, ears, poms, zip, etc) to the location your provided, not just one specific jar.